# switch back and forth between container-fluid and container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use the bootstrap grid. default width should be CSS container. from time to time elements should be set to 100% width of the container fluid. as a 1st example I used container and container-fluid alternately. in the second example, I used container-fluid as the standard and arranged containers in it. outside of container are then the 100% width. I could also use the container as a third option and break out to 100% width with `position: absolute`. which way is good? Can I somehow avoid addmargin? sometimes the height of the element in front is flexible and then no fixed height can be used

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 50px
}

.container>div {
  background: rgba(122, 122, 255, 1.00)
}

.container-fluid>div {
  background: rgba(122, 255, 122, 1.00)
}

.addmargin {
  margin-top: 100px
}

.containernext {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00) !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css " rel="stylesheet">

<div id="wrapper">
  <h2>Example 1</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div>Container 1</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div>Container 2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div>Container 3</div>
    <div>Container 4</div>
    <div>Container 5</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container-fluid addmargin">
    <div>Container 6</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div>Container 7</div>
    <div>Container 8</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:400px">
  <h2>Example 2</h2>
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container containernext">
      <div>Container 1</div>
      <div>Container 2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div style="margin-top:50px">Container 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is a matter of opinion, and therefore off topic here. Mine is that absolute positioning is rarely a good primary layout strategy.

Answer (score 1):

A bootstrap `container` is (in their words)

> Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/containers/

Why not make use of the `rows` and `cols` that come with it to get yourself a more predictable, stable layout.

In the example below, I have kept the same structure from example 1, but instead of just using `div` elements, I've put them in `row`s and `col`s, which are the building blocks of the Bootstrap grid system.

By just using the class `col` it will make that particular container always be the width of the parent. I've also made use of the margin utility classes to put some space between them.

This should give you the layout you want along with the flexibility to use the grid system properly, so if you want to break container 5 into 3 columns of different sizes, its as easy as adding a few more `col` classes in.

Further reading: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/

```css
.container .row{
    background: rgba(122,122,255,1.00)
}
.container-fluid .row{
    background: rgba(122,255,122,1.00)
}

.row{
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css " rel="stylesheet">

<div id="wrapper">
<h2>Example 1</h2>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row my-2"><div class="col">Container 1</div></div>
 </div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row my-2"><div class="col">Container 2</div></div>
</div>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row my-2"><div class="col">Container 3</div></div>
    <div class="row my-2"><div class="col">Container 4</div></div>
    <div class="row my-2"><div class="col">Container 5</div></div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row my-2"><div class="col">Container 6</div></div>
</div>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row my-2"><div class="col">Container 7</div></div>
    <div class="row my-2"><div class="col">Container 8</div></div> 
</div>
</div>
```